# Change object by pressing button while showing animation

Tags: processing

I'm trying to add animation in my code. What I have so far is an object that can be changed by pressing a button. So every time you press the button, the object changes (it is a tree and I'm changing its branches). Is it possible to add some kind of animation like snow? The problem with that is that I have to put it inside the draw method so it will be called automatically and make us think that it is animation. Thus, I also have to add the background / button and everything all the time. But I can't do that with my main object (tree) as I want to change it only when you press the button.

Is there any solution to that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I already coded the animation. But as I said I did it inside the draw method (which is executed automatically all the time). In that way I'm creating new background/buttons and all the elements over and over again (and thus the tree is hidden behind them)

Comment: You can edit your question, or you can delete it if you want. Just try to ask something concrete, like "How do I draw an ellipse with Win32/C++?", good questions are along those lines.

Comment: Please post some of your code, and add some concrete questions or issues that you are having. Like that well gladly help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To persist some objects while refreshing others, you either:

1. Refresh only part of the screen. Like, draw a shape (rect or whatever) with background colour erasing only part of screen
2. Conditionally draw selected objects. Use flags to selective draw what you need, every draw, and use `background()` to clear the whole screen every draw cycle.
3. Use layers. Erase one layer and not other as you need, display all them in draw. This is usually done with [PGraphics](http://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) objects. Search processing + layers to see samples. Here and/or in [processing forum](http://forum.processing.org/two/).

**EDIT:**
Here some simple examples of each approach:

1.

```java
/**
 * A very simple example of erasing just part of the screen to 
 * selective persist draws
 **/


void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  background(0);
  noStroke();
}

void draw() {
  fill(0);
  rect(0, 0, width/2, height);

  fill(120);
  ellipse(width/4, frameCount%width, 100, 100);
}

void mouseMoved() {
  fill(255);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
}
```

2.

```java
 /**
 * A very simple example of conditionally draw stuf 
 * to selective persist draws
 **/

ArrayList <PVector> points = new ArrayList <PVector>();
boolean showBalls = true; // any key to toogle

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  background(0);
  noStroke();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(30);
  rect(frameCount%width, 100, 200, 200);

  fill(120);
  ellipse(width/2, frameCount%width, 150, 150);

  fill(255);
  if (showBalls) {
    for (PVector p : points) {
      ellipse(p.x, p.y, 10, 10);
    }
  }
  if (points.size() > 500) {
    points.clear();
  }
}

void mouseMoved() {
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
  points.add(new PVector(mouseX, mouseY));
}

void keyPressed() {
  showBalls = !showBalls;
}
```

3.

```java
/**
 * A very simple example of using PGraphics as layers 
 * to selective persist draws
 **/

PGraphics layer;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  layer = createGraphics(width, height);
  layer.beginDraw();
  layer.fill(255);
  layer.endDraw();
  background(0);
  noStroke();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(30);
  rect(frameCount%width, 100, 200, 200);

  fill(120);
  ellipse(width/2, frameCount%width, 150, 150);
  image(layer, 0, 0);
}

void mouseMoved() {

  layer.beginDraw();
  layer.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
  layer.endDraw();
}
```