# Plotting a graph on a white box in Processing

Tags: python, graph, plot, processing

I am fairly new to Processing but I have managed to make a good amount of a GUI in the Python Mode. I wanted to graph some data on a white box. I don't want to use `background(0)` because that'll make the entire window white. Using a rectangular in the `draw()` function also did not help as the rectangular kept on refreshing the graph. I am trying to simulate the `hold on` function as in MATLAB

Here's my pseudo code:

```
class plotEverything:
      def __init__
      def plotAxis
      def plotGraph
      def clearGraph
def setup():
      size (800,600)
      p1 = plotEverything()
      background(0)
def draw():
      rect (100,100,200,200)
      fill(255)
      p1.drawAxis()
      p1.plotGraph()
```

Is there any way I can make that rectangle fixed in the background?

**EDIT Added graph class | Ignore indents(Assume they are all properly indented)** --

```
class graphData:
    def __init__(self, originX, originY, xUpper, yUpper):
    self.originX = originX
    self.originY = originY
    self.xUpper = xUpper
    self.yUpper = yUpper

    self.pointX1 = originX
    self.pointX2 = xUpper
    self.pointY1 = originY
    self.pointY2 = yUpper
    self.scaleFactorX = 10.0/(xUpper - originX) #Assuming data is between is 0 and 10
    self.scaleFactorY = 10.0/(originY - yUpper) #Assuming data is between is 0 and 1   

def drawAxis(self):
    stroke(255)
    strokeWeight(1.5)
    line(self.originX, self.originY, self.originX, self.yUpper) #y axis
    line(self.originX, self.originY, self.xUpper, self.originY) #x axis
def plotStaticData(self,data2Plot): #X-axis static
    ab = zip(data2Plot,data2Plot[1:],data2Plot[2:],data2Plot[3:])[::2]
    if ab: 

        (X1,Y1,X2,Y2) = ab[-1]
        print (X1,Y1,X2,Y2)

        self.pointX1 =  self.originX + ceil((float(X1) - 0.0)/self.scaleFactorX)
        self.pointX2 =  self.originX + ceil((float(X2) - 0.0)/self.scaleFactorX)
        self.pointY1 =  self.originY - ceil((float(Y1) - 0.0)/self.scaleFactorY)
        self.pointY2 =  self.originY - ceil((float(Y2) - 0.0)/self.scaleFactorY)
        stroke(255)
        strokeWeight(2.0)
        line(self.pointX1,self.pointY1,self.pointX2,self.pointY2)
def clearPlot(self):
    background(0)
    self.drawAxis()
```

Comment: What GUI toolkit are you using?  What do `plotAxis`, `plotGraph`, and `clearGraph` do?  Please post a minimum example that reproduces the problem.  The code you provided is too limited for us to be able to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: What do the `drawAxis()` and `drawGraph()` functions do? Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that uses basic calls to `ellipse()` instead?

Comment: Not sure if i got you, but looks that you want to persist some things while "clearing" others. If that's the case check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569117/change-object-by-pressing-button-while-showing-animation/23574355#23574355)

Comment: @v.k. i think that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Mathews_M_J Cool, I just edited that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569117/change-object-by-pressing-button-while-showing-animation/23574355#23574355) with a simple example of each case. All the in java mode though. HTH. :)